# SpritKit swift 3 Physics body collision and remove only one node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm using Sprit-kit on swift 3 my question is after shooting bullets to one node(i called it Planet) i don't want that node(Planet) disappear i want only bullets disappear from scene and my node(Planet) still continue running and if that node(Planet) collides with main Player both of them disappear (which there is no problem with that here).My problem is when bullets collide with that node both of them disappear how ever in collision function i just wrote Bullet.removefromParent() here is my code (i want keep my Planet after colliding with bullet and my bullet remove from scene ) :

```
 func CollitionPlannetWithBullet(_ Bullet : SKSpriteNode, Planet : SKSpriteNode){
   Bullet.removeFromParent()
 }
```

and this is the code in did begin contact function for planet and bullets:

```
 if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Planet) && 
     (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Bullet)) ||
     ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Bullet) &&
     (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Planet))  {
       CollitionPlannetWithBullet(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Planet:   secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
 }
```

Comment: you are confusing yourself,  in your if statement, you say body1 or body2 can be bullets, but in your `CollitionPlannetWithBullet` (spelling error?) you are saying only body1 is bullet.  Try and remain consistent

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way to do this is to sublcass SKSpriteNode which then allows you to use if let to treat each node in a collision using its one subclassed functions.

I would recommend reading up on subclassing and polymorphism as it will make your code much cleaner and give you a lot more flexibility in how you build things.

```
func evalChainGun_Drone(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact){
    let nodeA = contact.bodyA.node
    let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node

    //A Items
    if let shotA = nodeA as? ChaingunBullet {
        shotA.damage()}

    if let droneA = nodeA as? Drone {
        droneA.weaponDamage(droneA.HP_Class, damage: 1, node: droneA, contactLocation: contact.contactPoint)
    }

    //B Items
    if let shotB = nodeB as? ChaingunBullet {
        shotB.damage()}

    if let droneB = nodeB as? Drone {
        droneB.weaponDamage(droneB.HP_Class, damage: 1, node: droneB, contactLocation: contact.contactPoint)
    }
}
```

I hope that is helpful.

Best regards,
Undead-Earth

Comment: how does this help at all?

Comment: The problem with spritekit is that you don't really have any control over which node is which contact so you need to handle both conditions. While I agree that duplicative code might not be a best practice I'm not sure of any way to fox that with Swift.

Comment: In term of how this helps.  If you subclass your "shot" you can then make sure that the actions that you call on it when it is involved in a contact are only called on that - and the same for the other side of the contact.  For the shot I may just remove it - and for the target I might make it explode with an SKEmitter node and then remove it.

Comment: You definitely have control. Check the categorybitmask,  whatever is lowest assign to A. The other B

Comment: As for the help,  it still doesn't answer the problem,  the OP getting confused

Comment: thank you guys for your help but i still not sure how to fix it if anyone can help i would appreciate.